# use memcpy for device arrays in openacc

Tags: openacc

Please, help. 
1) I need to use memcpy for moving the arrays allocated on the gpu. i can not use std::memcpy because it "has no acc routine" (compiler output). My code is

```
const int GL=100000;
Particle particles[GL];
int cp01[2][GL];
#pragma acc declare create(particles,cp01)
...
```

i read that cudaMemcpy can be used with openacc. In function_device() ([not able to fill the array allocated on the gpu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47395226/not-able-to-fill-the-array-allocated-on-the-gpu)) i call from the host

```
#pragma acc data copy(cp)
{
  cudaMemcpy(&particles[cp01[0][0]],&particles[cp01[1][0]],cp*sizeof(Particle),cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice);
}
```

i use the header

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
```

for using CUDA. And build the project as

```
 cmake ../src -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=pgc++ -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-acc -Minfo=all -Mcuda=llvm"
```

The program compiles, but does not work, it hangs with no output in the console line. **How to move arrays allocated on the device (using cudaMemcpy or in some another manner)? Is that one include enough for using CUDA? Do i build the project correctly (using -Mcuda=llvm is necessary or not)?**
2) i also have another question: if one writes

```
#pragma acc parallel loop
for(int i=0; i<N; ++i)
{...}
```

the variable N must be allocated on the host only or it may be also on the gpu?

Answer (score 1):

Since "cudaMemcpy" is a host side call where you want to pass in the device pointers, you'll want to use a "host_data" directive. No need to copy "cp" since you'll want to use the host value. Also make sure the host values of "cp01" are current.

Something like the following:

```
#pragma acc host_data use_device(particles) 
  { 
  cudaMemcpy(&particles[cp01[0][0]],&particles[cp01[1] [0]],cp*sizeof(Particle),cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice); 
  }
```