# not able to use cudaMemcpy with openacc

Tags: openacc

I have the following code

```
const int GL=100000;
Particle particles[GL];
int cp01[2][GL];
#pragma acc declare create(particles,cp01)
...
```

where i call from the host

```
#pragma acc update self(cp01)
#pragma acc host_data use_device(particles) 
{ 
  cudaMemcpy(&particles[cp01[0][0]],&particles[cp01[1][0]],cp*sizeof(Particle),cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice); 
}
```

following the advice ([use memcpy for device arrays in openacc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47438995/use-memcpy-for-device-arrays-in-openacc/47519890#47519890)).
I use the header

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
```

to use cudaMemcpy() and build the project as

```
cmake ../src -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=pgc++ -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-acc -Minfo=all"
```

but the compiler gives

```
CMakeFiles/AOS_GPU_LIFE.dir/nbody.cpp.o: In function `function_device()':
/home/70-gaa/source/GPU/AOS_GPU_LIFE_map_sort_new/nbody.cpp:175: undefined reference to `cudaMemcpy'
pgacclnk: child process exit status 1: /usr/bin/ld
CMakeFiles/AOS_GPU_LIFE.dir/build.make:94: recipe for target 'AOS_GPU_LIFE' failed
make[2]: *** [AOS_GPU_LIFE] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/AOS_GPU_LIFE.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/AOS_GPU_LIFE.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The line 175 is the line with cudaMemcpy. If I add the compiler argument "-Mcuda=8.0", the program compiles and links, but when i launch it, it simply hangs with no output in the console line. May be, i did not link some cuda libraries properly?
My compiler is pgc++ 17.4-0 64-bit target on x86-64 Linux -tp sandybridge.
I opened a new theme because could not post the code in the comment to the previous one. Please, help me solve this problem.

Comment: The link error is because you're missing the CUDA runtime libraries on your link line which are brought in when you add the flag "-Mcuda=8.0".  As for the hang, I'm not sure.  You can set the environment variable "PGI_ACC_DEBUG=1" to see all the OpenACC runtime calls which might help in showing where the hang occurs.  If it's hanging in the cudaMemcpy, then I'd check the values of "cp" and "cp1".  If you can't figure it out, I'd need a reproducing example to help.

Answer (score 1):

Andrey sent me the code and it appears to be a compiler issue when using variables used in a "declare" directive in a "host_data" region with the addition of the "-Mcuda" option.  I have filed problem reports with the PGI compiler team for these issues (TPRs #24968 and #24969).  The work around is to put these variables in a "data" region instead of a "declare" directive.